# Docker React The build failed because the process exited too early

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am working on a `microservices` project using `docker` and `kubenetes`, here I have one client and other services for backend.

I am facing the issue when I see the log of my client (React js).

> The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably
> means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the
> process.

**Docker file for client**

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**/infra/k8s/client-depl.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: client
        image: shanbiswas/client:latest
        # resources:
        #   limits:
        #     memory: "256Mi"
        #     cpu: "500m"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: client
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

Also if I run `kubectl get pods` then I can see that the client is not running.
[image]

Git repo :- https://github.com/shanbiswas/node-react-microservices-udemy-blog-project

Comment: Does the container run in plain Docker, without Kubernetes?  What are in the logs of the container?  `kubectl`'s output is plain text; [please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Surprisingly, I uncommented the resource limit and it started working again, with no out-of-memory errors.